# Django Password Reset Form Not Showing When Using DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I'm facing an issue with my Django application involving the password reset functionality. When the password reset link is sent via the standard Django website flow, everything works as expected: the user receives an email with a link, and upon clicking it, they are taken to a page with a form to reset their password.

However, when the reset link is sent through a Django Rest Framework (DRF) API (triggered from a Flutter app), the user still receives the email with a link, but the page that opens does not show the password reset form. The rest button only appears, but the password reset form itself is missing.

Here's the relevant part of my CustomPasswordResetConfirmView in Django:

```
class CustomPasswordResetConfirmView(PasswordResetConfirmView):
    form_class = SetPasswordForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_complete')
    template_name = 'users/password_reset_confirm.html'

    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters('new_password1', 'new_password2'))
    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.form_class(user=self.request.user)
        return context
```

And the template users/password_reset_confirm.html is as follows:

```
        <main class="mt-5" >
            <div class="container dark-grey-text mt-5">
                <div class="content-section">
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Reset Password</legend>
                            {{ form|crispy }}
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Reset Password</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
```

I am not sure exactly what to look for it is either the link that is sent to the user to reset no correct as when the email is received from the website shows the link as following:

```
Subject: Password reset on [Displayname]
You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at [Displayname].

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:

https://www.[Domain].com/password-reset-confirm/NTM/bxogt6-68772***************f41836/

Your username, in case you’ve forgotten: Username

Thanks for using our site!

The [Displayname]team
```

while from the DRF API flutter looks like this:

```
Subject: [Displayname] Password Reset E-mail
Hello from [Displayname]!

You're receiving this e-mail because you or someone else has requested a password for your user account.
It can be safely ignored if you did not request a password reset. Click the link below to reset your password.

https://www.[Domain].com/password-reset-confirm/1h/bxogub-7eebb4**************deaa0e/

In case you forgot, your username is Username.

Thank you for using [Displayname]!
www.[Domain].com
```

here is the Django settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ]
}
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER':
        'api.serializers.PasswordResetSerializer',
}
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS=['users.models.EmailBackend']
```

here is the template for the users/templates/users/password_reset_email.html

even though I noticed it is not used at all due to the settings:

```
{% autoescape off %}
You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/api/{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}

Your username, in case you've forgotten: {{ user.username }}

Thanks for using our site!

The {{ site_name }} team.

{% endautoescape %}
```

***UPDATE*** I have noticed the DRF is using the default way to reset the password as I have removed the CustomPasswordResetConfirmView view and from the url and the same error is showing

Answer (score 0):

did you install any library / package that related to password reset / auth? because I think it's an email template from the library.

For me, I think is more simple if I use the library to handle that. for example, I usually use [dj-rest-auth](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) to handle related to auth, registration, forgot password, and reset password.

**For the DRF with Flutter.**

The flow should be:

1. flutter hit endpoint reset password
2. Django sends an email to the user
3. flutter handle deep link to create a new password inside flutter app
4. flutter hit endpoint password reset confirm with the params `uid`, `token` and `new password`

Comment: it is but when the link is clicked the password reset form is empty